# loading csv data in Gephi

Tags: graph, gephi

I have data in form of , I use label as a form of edge attribute

```
Source      Target     Weight    Label
 620         426       3500      DERM
 643         573       109000    AMP
 669         616       199200    ABG
```

but when I load the file I get around 7000 nodes, which shouldn't be as there is only 60 nodes,

Comment: Are you also importing a separate node matrix? If not then Gephi might think that you are creating as many nodes as the maximum id in the source, target columns. Not 100% sure but this might be your case

Comment: Hi no I am not importing a separate node matrix will try it out then

Comment: Add a separate node matrix and be careful to include only the node ids appearing in the `source, target` columns. This can easily be done by filtering the non-duplicates, in excel